# Array of promise with results separately

Tags: javascript, arrays, callback, promise, ecmascript-6

Basically, I'm looking for something like `Promise.all()`, but one that calls the function in `then()` for each result, as soon as that result is ready. It's trivial to write using standard callbacks like this (file reading example):

```
function foo(files, bar) {
  for (let file of files) {
    const fr = new FileReader();
    fr.onload = e => bar(e.target.result);
    fr.readAsDataURL(file);
  }
}
```

I'm sure there's a library out there that does what I want, but I'd like to do that in pure JS.

To clarify, I would like to have something like this:

```
function foo(files) {
  // do something here;
}

foo(['1','2','3']).then(/* do something here with separate results */);`
```

Comment: Does the `forEach` array method do what you want? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Comment: That would mean I couldn't write a simple .then() after calling the Promise function.

Comment: Would you mind adding an example demonstrating how it doesn't work? jib's answer below seems to fit from my POV

Comment: why don't you do promise.race to get the first result and promise.all for the rest.

Answer (score 4):

Just use `map`:

```
let read = file => return new Promise(resolve => {
  const fr = new FileReader();
  fr.onload = e => resolve(e.target.result);
  fr.readAsDataURL(file);
});

Promise.all(files.map(file => read(file).then(bar)))
  .then(allResultsFromBar => { /* use results array */ });
```

Note that `.then` promotes anything returned from a function it executes to a promise (i.e. it calls `Promise.resolve` on it implicitly), so `Promise.all` is guaranteed to receive an array of promises no matter what `bar` returns.

Comment: But map needs to return promises. Missing explanation for that

Comment: It does, because `.then` promotes anything returned from a function it executes to a promise (i.e. it calls `Promise.resolve` implicitly on it.)

Comment: huh? Not if `read()` has no `then`. Where does `read()` even come from?

Comment: OK... now there are promises in map, there weren't before

Comment: I want the function in `then()` called each time a result is ready, one result at a time.

Comment: That's `bar`, and it gets called each time a result is ready.

Comment: @jib needs to make sense regardless of how you enter it. You have to admit that initial answer was not very complete

Comment: That would work, but I would still have to have that callback as an argument, is there no way to return something from a function so that I could just call `then(bar)` on it and be done with it?

Comment: Good answer - one nit. You want to make the `new Promise` in `read`  wrap the whole function and not just the last line, if `readAsDataUrl` throws synchronously you have a mix of having to handle both sync and async rejections.

Comment: @Krzaku Not sure what you mean. You can inline whatever code you want in that `then`, even keep that then-chain going: `.then(bar)` --> `.then(file = bar(file)).then(result => fum(result, 3))`. These are all the building blocks you need.

Comment: @jib I want to have a function `readFiles` that takes a list of files as its only argument, and I want it to return some kind of promise that I could call `then()` on, and the function that I would put in `then()` would be called separately for each of the files.

Comment: @Krzaku That would not be a promise, and would obfuscate your code IMHO. Someone else would need to be the enabler on that one.

Comment: @Krzaku It would be best to stick around to the common/standard programming pattern :)

Comment: It's worth noting that this works because a `Promise` chain is equivalent to a single `Promise` that is, `Promise.all` can be applied to both.

Answer (score 0):

Working from @jib's answer and the comment :

> I want to have a function readFiles that takes a list of files as its only argument, and I want it to return some kind of promise that I could call then() on, and the function that I would put in then() would be called separately for each of the files.

That's not quite possible because a `.then()` callback is only called once, not once per result delivered by `Promise.all()`.

This is close :

```
let read = file => return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const fr = new FileReader();
    fr.onload = e => resolve(e.target.result);
    fr.onerror = reject; // don't forget to reject on error
    fr.readAsDataURL(file);
});

let readFiles = files => return Promise.all(files.map(read)); // <<<<< this is the line you seek
```

Allowing you to write :

```
const files = ["...", "...", "..."];
readFiles(files)
.then(allFileResults => allFileResults.map(bar)); // bar is your function for processing file results
// possibly chain another .then() if required to observe/process bar()'s results
```

Thus `bar()` will operate on each of the file contents in turn.

However, in getting the code as close as possible to what you asked for :

- your "as soon as" requirement isn't truly meet; the `allFileContents.map(bar)` process is downstream of `Promise.all()`, therefore waits for *all* files to be read before commencing the `bar()` calls.
- any single error in `readFiles(...)` will (without some sort of error recovery) scupper the whole enterprise; `allFileContents.map(bar)` would never be called on *any* of the files; that may be good or bad depending on your application; good news though, error recover is easily inserted.
- as written, `bar()` must be synchronous; if not, you can simply insert another `Promise.all()`, ie `allFileResults => Promise.all(allFileResults.map(bar))`.

For these reasons, @jib's solution may well be the one to go for but it depends on what the application demands.