# Array of Promises resolve Promises as soon as completed?

Tags: javascript, promise

I have an array of Promises, and I want to trigger certain actions on them as soon as they complete. `Promises.all` isn't quite what I'm looking for since it waits until all `Promises` in the `Iterable` have completed. `Promises.race` returns whatever the first Promise which complete returns.

Assume that you can only use: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Comment: `promises.forEach(p => p.then(doStuff))`

Comment: Can you post a code sample?  Depending on how you're creating your promises, you can generally use `.then()` within the individual promises and resolve the array with `Promise.all`.

Comment: @4castle Don't forget to `.catch()` errors when doing that. Or better, **don't use `forEach`**, instead use `map` and do something with the result (including error handling)

Comment: @Bergi They can still use `forEach`. The next line could be `Promise.all(promises).catch(handleIt)`

Comment: @4castle No they can't, that would cause unhandled promise rejections for the promises created by `then` in the `forEach` when the `promises` get rejected

Comment: @Bergi We have very little information on what they're trying to do here. `doStuff` might not return anything at all.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Array of promise with results separately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38291873/array-of-promise-with-results-separately)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking into account you want to use Vanilla JS, if you want they to execute them concurrently and as soon as they are resolved you could do something like this:

```
// create a Promise that is resolved after passed millisecs with millisecs * 2 as value
const createP = (ms) => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(ms * 2), ms));

// your array of Promises
const pArray = [createP(1000), createP(200), createP(500)];

// map() and Promise.all() is necessary in order to wait until all the promises are executed
Promise.all(pArray.map(promise => { 
  // log each result
  return promise.then(console.log);
}))
.catch(err =>{
  // do some error handling here if necessary
});

// it should log 400, 1000, 2000 in this order
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a method `promiseSerial` that will resolve promises sequentially instead of in parallel.

Here's an example implementation:

```
/*
* promiseSerial resolves Promises sequentially.
* @example
* const urls = ['/url1', '/url2', '/url3']
* const funcs = urls.map(url => () => $.ajax(url))
*
* promiseSerial(funcs)
*   .then(console.log)
*   .catch(console.error)
*/
const promiseSerial = funcs =>
  funcs.reduce((promise, func) =>
    promise.then(result => func().then(Array.prototype.concat.bind(result))),
    Promise.resolve([]))

// some url's to resolve
const urls = ['/url1', '/url2', '/url3']

// convert each url to a function that returns a promise
const funcs = urls.map(url => () => $.ajax(url))

// execute Promises in serial
promiseSerial(funcs)
  .then(console.log)
  .catch(console.error)
```

from: https://hackernoon.com/functional-javascript-resolving-promises-sequentially-7aac18c4431e

Comment: This is serial, he's asking for a concurrent solution I think.