# What would be the equivalent of asyncio.as_completed in javascript?

Tags: javascript, promise

- `Promise.all` only resolves when all promises resolve, rejects when the first promise rejects
- `Promise.allSettled` only resolves once all promises settle
- `Promise.any` resolves only the first resolved promise, rejects when all the promises reject
- `Promise.race` settles with the same result of the first promise to settle

It seems that `Promise` in Javascript does not have the equivalent of `asyncio.as_completed` which yields Promises in the order they settle.

**Is it possible to achieve the same logic of `asyncio.as_completed` with user code?**

Comment: This is an exact duplicate of: [Array of Promises resolve Promises as soon as completed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45092395/array-of-promises-resolve-promises-as-soon-as-completed)

Comment: @KevinB disagree: in python that function *executes* the coros and returns await-ables, in JS the Promise code runs as soon as it's constructed and Promise.all turns the container inside out, array of promise -> promise of array. AFAICT there is no equivalent JS semantic, or to be more precise there's no *need* for that function in JS, but I don't think that makes it a dupe of the other. I could be wrong.

Comment: I think you're looking for [async generator yielding promise results as they are resolved](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70044213/1048572), does that the same as `as_completed` in python?

Comment: The [python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.as_completed) mention that "*Generators yielding tasks are not accepted*" for some reason. If you'd like something that can handle even that, see [Unordered resolution of a list of promises](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74293770/1048572)